# Why does 'false' match all records in an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe this is an obvious one but why is it that the query

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug = false;
```

returns all rows?

I ask because I made the mistake of accidentally having PHP set the variable for the WHERE argument to false... on a delete query.

Comment: And what was the exact php code? Note that `echo false;` does not output anything in php.

Comment: To answer jeroen, it was CodeIgniter's $this->input->post('inputSlug') where I actually should have retrieved the 4th uri segment. As the POST variable hadn't been set, the function returned FALSE.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate question, I did try searching before asking but couldn't find that question as I wasn't really sure what to even search for!